# Get document from collection using specific field in firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am looking to get a document by using the `formId` field in firebase with Node.js . The `formId` is in a map so I'm not sure how to use the `get()` function for it. Here is my React code which  hasn't worked. I believe it doesnt work because the `formId` field is contained in the `formMetaData` map.

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        const firestoreRef = firebase.firestore().collection('Forms');
        // Create a query against the collection where we can match the formId
        const queryRef = firestoreRef.where('formId', '==', ID_HERE);

      }, []);
```

Also here is the set up of the DB:
[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the dot notation to access nested fields:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const firestoreRef = firebase.firestore().collection('Forms');
  // Create a query against the collection where we can match the formId
  const queryRef = firestoreRef.where('formMetaData.FormId', '==', ID_HERE); 
                                                  ^^^
  queryRef.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    // total matched documents
    const matchedDocs = querySnapshot.size
    if (matchedDocs) {
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        console.log(doc.id, "=>", doc.data())
      })
    } else {
      console.log("0 documents matched the query")
    }
  })
}, []);
```

`queryRef` is a [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query) and has `get()` method which returns a Promise containing [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot).

The `docs` property on QuerySnapshot is an array of [`QueryDocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot) and you can use `data()` method on each DocumentSnapshot to access it's data.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the `formId` via the `formMetaData` object by updating your code as follows:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const firestoreRef = firebase.firestore().collection('Forms');
    // Create a query against the collection where we can match the formId
    const queryRef = firestoreRef.where('formMetaData.formId', '==', ID_HERE);

  }, []);
```